# Unit Testing - Setting Model Property Values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I'm currently in the process of writing a unit test, which is failing... It states: `failed. Expected:<0>. Actual:<16>.` I understand that this occurs because the `RateManagement` model is not getting set properly, but unsure how to set this data in my test.

> **Question:** How can I populate the `RateManagement` model so that I can test the values correctly?

**Failing Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void BabysitterBusiness_StartTimeBedTimeAndEndTimeAreRecorded_ReturnsCorrectAmountDue()
{
    // Arrange
    var data = new RateManagement
    {
        TotalBedtimeHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(3),
        TotalHoursBeforeBedtime = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
        TotalOvertimeHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(4)
    };

    // Act
    var result = _business.CalculatePaymentDue();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(result, 16M);
}
```

**RateManagement Class**

```
public class RateManagement 
    {
        public TimeSpan TotalBedtimeHours { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TotalOvertimeHours { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TotalHoursBeforeBedtime { get; set; }
    }
```

**Business Class**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using BabysitterKata.Models;

namespace BabysitterKata.Business
{
    public class BabysitterBusiness
    {
        private readonly TimeManagement _timeManagement;
        private readonly RateManagement _rateManagement;
        private readonly HourlyRate _hourlyRate = new HourlyRate
        {
            StartingRate = 12M,
            BedtimeRate = 8M,
            OvertimeRate = 16M
        };

        public BabysitterBusiness(TimeManagement timeManagement, RateManagement rateManagement)
        {
            _timeManagement = timeManagement;
            _rateManagement = rateManagement;
        }

        public decimal CalculatePaymentDue()
        {
            // calculate amount due for total hours
            var beforeBedtimeAmountDue = _hourlyRate.StartingRate * _rateManagement.TotalHoursBeforeBedtime.Hours;
            var duringBedtimeAmountDue = _hourlyRate.BedtimeRate * _rateManagement.TotalBedtimeHours.Hours;
            var afterHoursAmountDue = _hourlyRate.OvertimeRate * _rateManagement.TotalOvertimeHours.Hours;

            // rounding up if not at start of hour
            if (_rateManagement.TotalHoursBeforeBedtime.Minutes != 00)
            {
                beforeBedtimeAmountDue += _hourlyRate.StartingRate;
            }

            if (_rateManagement.TotalBedtimeHours.Minutes != 00)
            {
                duringBedtimeAmountDue += _hourlyRate.BedtimeRate;
            }

            if (_rateManagement.TotalOvertimeHours.Minutes != 00)
            {
                afterHoursAmountDue += _hourlyRate.OvertimeRate;
            }

            return beforeBedtimeAmountDue + duringBedtimeAmountDue + afterHoursAmountDue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretend you're the compiler and runtime. play this program "in your mind". do you expect any other result?

Comment: @Amit, I'd expect it to return 0 currently because I haven't assigned the values in the test. I'd think that there is an easy way to mock the data up though.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Currently, my model properties are not getting assigned. How can I set my model properties in my test so that I can properly test different scenarios with the `CalculatePaymentDue()` method.

Comment: For example, the `TotalBedTimeHours` is 0... How can I set the data up so that it is actually 5.

Comment: How is your code designed to get these properties?

Comment: I have other methods within my `business` class that assign the total hours calculated to that model property. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nothing here makes much sense honestly, but if you want to learn how to design code for testing, look up SOLID OOP.

Comment: @Amit, thanks for the help... I'll definitely take a look at SOLID OOP.

Comment: Good luck and enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You are constructing the data instance.

Just pass that and 2 more similar instances to the constructor of _business.

```
// Arrange
var data = new RateManagement
{
    TotalBedtimeHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(3),
    TotalHoursBeforeBedtime = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
    TotalOvertimeHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(4)
};

var timeData = new TimeManagement { // your properties };

// Act
var business = new BabysitterBusiness(timeData, data);
var result = business.CalculatePaymentDue();

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(result, 16M);
```

Your RateManagement and TimeManagement seem to be simple data objects, so there is no need to Mock it using a framework or anything. You can pass in the real instance with data.